# Transform HTML in Haskell

Tags: html, haskell, transformation

I want to transform a valid HTML with not very deep level of nesting into another HTML with more restricted rules.

Only the following tags are supported in the resulting HTML:

```
<b></b>, <strong></strong>, <i></i>, <em></em>, <a
href="URL"></a>, <code></code>, <pre></pre>
```

Nested tags are not allowed at all.

For the rest of the tags and their combinations I have to create some sort of rules how to handle each.
So I have to convert something like:

`<p>text</p>` into simple string `text` with linebreak,

`<b>text <a href="url">link</a> text</b>` into `text link text`

`<a href="url">text<code> code here</code></a>` into `<a href="url">text code here</a>` because `<code>` is nested inside `<a>` and so on.

For example HTML (linebreaks are only for convenience):

```
<p>long paragraph <a href="url">link</a> </p>
<p>another text <pre><code>my code block</code></pre> the rest of description</p>
<p><code>inline monospaced text with <a href="url">link</a></code></p>
```

Should be transformed into:

```
long paragraph <a href="url">link</a>

another text <code>my code block</code> the rest of description

<code>inline monospaced text with link</code>
```

Any suggestion on the way to solve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation, I have found a pretty elegant solution in my opinion. It's based on [tagsoup](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tagsoup-0.13.10) library. The library has `Text.HTML.TagSoup.Tree` module which helps to parse HTML into tree structure.

It also contains `transformTree` function which does transformation pretty trivial. Documentation of that function says:

> This operation is based on the Uniplate transform function. Given a list of trees, it applies the function to every tree in a bottom-up manner.

You can read about Uniplate more [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/uniplate).

This is the code I was satisfied with:

```
import Text.HTML.TagSoup
import Text.HTML.TagSoup.Tree

convert = transformTree f
    where
      f (TagLeaf (TagOpen "br" _)) = [TagLeaf (TagText "\n")] -- line breaks
      f (TagLeaf (TagOpen _ _)) = [] -- ignore all tags without closing pairs
      f (TagBranch "a" attrs inner) = tagExtr "a" attrs inner -- keeps href for <a>
      f (TagBranch "p" _ inner) = inner ++ [(TagLeaf (TagText "\n"))]
      f (TagBranch "pre" _ [TagBranch "code" _ inner]) = tagExtr "pre" [] inner -- <pre><code> -> <code>
      f (TagBranch tag _ inner) = if tag `elem` allowedTags then tagExtr tag [] inner else inner
      f x = [x]

tagExtr tag attrs inner = [TagBranch tag attrs [(extractFrom inner)]]

allowedTags = ["b", "i", "a", "code", "a", "pre", "em", "strong"]

extractFrom x = TagLeaf $ TagText $ (innerText . flattenTree) x
```